# Does rotating a soda can on a table prevent it from fizzing over when opened?

Tags: physics

In [this scene](https://9gag.com/gag/aze3x6q) from [Season 6 Episode 7](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12187040/) of *Better Call Saul*, the character Howard Hamlin shows that one can stop a shaken soda can from exploding when opened by first rotating it vertically while it is standing on a table. He explains

> Something about the centrifugal force. It pulls the bubbles from the inside of the can

Does this trick work?

Comment: Somewhat related: Tapping beer can does not help: https://www.technologyreview.com/2019/12/11/131624/does-tapping-the-bottom-of-a-beer-can-really-stop-it-fizzing-over/ Also Sister-site on chemistry does not support this https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47071/what-causes-soda-to-fizz-and-how-can-it-be-stopped

Comment: The trick is to use vibration to get bubbles out of the soda, and to encourage more to form and rise to the top.  Then, careful opening of the can will release the gas without the foam.  The soda will be a little flat either way.

Comment: If you're willing to make the sacrifice, you could try it with a can of seltzer (less mess to clean up) and let us know.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis yes, that's the claim in the question.  Restating it does not answer the question, which is "does the technique work as described by the theory?"  My experience is that it does not.